# Triple Monitor Issue, 12.10 64bit

Tags: 12.10, nvidia

Currently I have 3 monitors across 2 GPU's (nvidia 560ti), in ubuntu 12.04 i installed the additional drivers which allowed me to use the mosaic command to enable all three monitors.

After upgrading to 12.10 i have read that Additional Drivers no longer work and I must use the software sources version, whenever I try these I am presented with a smaller resolution desktop with no GUI (albeit I do get 2 monitors), and thus have to resort back to the native drivers.

Any help appreciated, and I will provide whatever information you need.